# Div Button wrapper width?

Tags: html, css, button, wrapper, actinic

First post here.
I have shopping cart software called **sellerdeck** previously actinic. There is a lot of different code involved.

I have a button wrapper which has pre defined text inserted. I am trying to change the width of the button to a fixed width but pretty much everything I tried, from info I've found here and elsewhere, breaks the code and the button either disappears, does not function, or shrinks to about 10px.

Is it possible to set the width in the following code or is it likely that I will have to do it elsewhere within my software?

This code creates a small rectangle green button with white text that reads "Add to Cart" the text is pulled from code elsewhere in my software.

```
<div class="button-wrapper cart-button-wrapper">
  <input value="<Actinic:Variable Name="CartButtonText"/>" name="_<Actinic:Variable Name="ProductID"/>" type="submit" class="button cart-button" onclick="return ValidateChoices('<actinic:variable name="ProductID" />');"/>
</div>
```

Any help would be great, I've tried padding and manage to get top padding to work but that's it.

Michael

Comment: It would be difficult to help you without seeing the CSS styles that your button currently has. Perhaps try to emulate the problem in JSFiddle, then we can edit that to what you need.

Comment: Ok, the code is now showing in the post, the css style sheet that i have for this page has absolutely no reference to the button wrapper at all. All I want to do is make the button bigger and maybe increase the font size. Ive got a feeling no one here can help as ive probably got to do this elsewhere in my software ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button widths can be simply set by css class.
If the width is not displaying as expected then there is probably an issue with **specificity**.

To test if the class is being overwritted elsewhere in your code you can add `!important` to your classese attributes or add an `inline style` attribute to increase the items specificity.

**e.g** `<input style="width:150px;"/>`

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: All styling should be placed in your style sheet and not in your html (inline) whenever possible.

If the width now applies then it is being overwritten elsewhere.

I recommend you use your browsers debugger ***(f12)*** to see which style is taking priority.

```css
.button-wrapper{
  width:150px;
  height:40px;
  font-size:16px;
  display:block;
}
.button-wrapper input{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper cart-button-wrapper">
  <input value="CartButtonText" type="submit" class="button cart-button"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, im assuming your top piece of code has to go in the css style sheet and not into my code like your bottom piece of code ?

Comment: Classes should be placed in your style sheet. And not in your html. However when this is not possible you may have to add it to your html.